# @Transactional method calling a method in the same class

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I have a class UserService which has a method saveUser() and saveAmount() as shown below.

```
class UserService {
    
    @Transactional
    public void saveUsers() {
        saveUser1 to db;
        saveUser2 to db;
        saveAmount();
        saveUser3 to db;
    }
    
    public void saveAmount() {
        saveAmount1 to db;
        saveAmount2 to db // throws exception
        saveAmount3 to db;
    }
}
```

As per Spring AOP, when saveAmount() is called, the proxy won't be triggered and we have the same transaction of saveUsers method continuing with saveAmount, so any exception in saveAmount (say in line 2 of the method) if occured will rollback saveUser1 to db and saveUser2 to db.

Question : Will saveAmount1 to db be rolled back as well ?

I tried replicating this on my local machine and I am expecting that saveAmount1 to db won't rollback as it was called from them same object and AOP did not kick in.

Comment: Which exception did you test? Transactional will roll back when you throw RuntimeException, and other extends classes. `throw new Exception()` won't work.

Comment: Code documentation: `By default, a transaction will be rolled back on RuntimeException and Error but not on checked exceptions (business exceptions).`

Comment: A runtime exception is thrown on saveAmount2 to db. Will it rollback saveAmount2 to db as well ?

Comment: It must restore everything that happened in the transaction block - including nested calls (another @Transaction annotation will be ignored if not used bean proxy, for example: same instance). But if you test with the database connection, it makes complete evidence for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AOP does not kick it if you are self invoking a `@Transactional` method only means the `@Transactional` on the method that is being self-invoked will not have any effect.

But now `saveAmount()` does not have any `@Transactional` annotated on it , so it is nothing to do with whether the AOP will kick in or not.

In this case , both `saveUsers()` and `saveAmount()` execute in the same transaction. All codes in the same transaction has all or nothing behaviour meaning the changes to DB are either all success or all fail. All fail also imply that any codes that throw exception will rollback all DB changes that are executed successfully. So if `saveAmount2` throws exception , every DB changes will rollback including saveAmount1.

Comment: So even if the saveAmount() method was annotated with @Transactional annotation, AOP would have not kicked in and it would have been the same result. Is this correct ?

Comment: yes------------

Comment: Actually, it is much simpler than this. Just think about what a transaction is: an atomic set of operations on a DB. The effect on annotating a method with `@Transactional` simply is, that a transaction is started before entering that method and committed or rolled back right after exiting it. What happens in between and how many more methods are called, is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: That sounds pretty simple @kriegaex to understand
Thanks !